# I'm having trouble understanding what a variable does right before a for loop

Tags: python, loops, return, enumerate

I'm new to python and I'm having trouble understanding what the variable before the 'for' in this return statement does. I've got a slightly modified version of this code from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114521/python-hangman-game-with-multiple-letters-in-one-word)

```py
word = "boom"

def find_all(word, guess):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]
```

I understand that the function is getting every occurence of the user's guessed letter in the word "boom", creates 'i' for index and 'letter' for the value that the enumerate function is about to give. The end is stating this will happen if the letter in the word is equal to the guess in the word.

What does the

```py
i for i
```

do though? I cannot find anything on it, and when I take it out it breaks the code.
Is there anyway way to write this not in the return?

My modified code then later on states

```py
board = "_" * len(word)
listed_board = list(board)

while board != word:
    guess = input("Input a letter here ").lower()
    if guess in word:
        indices = find_all(word, guess)
        print(indices)
        listed_board = list(board)
        for i in indices:
            listed_board[i] = guess
            board = "".join(listed_board)
        print(listed_board)
```

The only other part I don't understand is when it's saying

```
listed_board[i] = guess
```

What is this doing? On the listed_board it is only underscores at this point, so how is it locating the correct position to insert the word and setting it to the user's guess?

Appreciate the replies, thanks!

Comment: `listed_board[i] = guess` simply fills the list with the value of variable `guess` because you have it inside the for loop. So all your list elements are now `guess`. So it is not locating the correct position but in fact your whole list is having the same variable

Comment: this might help https://stackoverflow.com/q/10777271/5986907 ... `i, letter` is a length 2 tuple. It's iterating over these tuples and picking out the index `i` if the `letter == guess`

Comment: That list comprehension is equivalent to `for i, letter in enumerate(word): if letter == guess: lst.append(i)` (with the `lst` being implicit here). The `word = "boom"` at the very beginning actually doesn't do anything in that snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so here is how your code works:

```
word = "boom"

def find_all(word, guess):
    return [i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]
```

`enumerate(word)` creates new iterable object. Each letter from `'boom'` gets its own idex: `[(0, 'b'), (1, 'o'), (2, 'o'), (3, 'm')]`. 
Now `for` loop iterate through this new object, where `i` is equal to index (number from the list above), and `letter` (variable) is equal to the letter (value from the list). Therefore this function will return a list of the index(s) for your guess. If the guess is equal `'b'` it will return `[0]`, for `'o'` it will be `[1, 2]`, for `'m'`, `[3]`, else this list will be empty.

Going further:

```
while board != word:
    guess = input("Input a letter here ").lower()
    if guess in word:
        indices = find_all(word, guess)  # This will return all index where 'guess' is equal to letter from world. For example for word='foo', guess='o' it will return [1,2]
        print(indices)
        listed_board = list(board)
        for i in indices:  # for each index you have found:
            listed_board[i] = guess  # replace '_' with correct letter (guess)
            board = "".join(listed_board)  # change list to string
        print(listed_board)
```

Hope this code is more obvious to you right now.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The only other question I have now is at the listed_board[i] = guess. How is it replacing the '_' in the correct position? Thanks.

Comment: Basically, strings are immutable in Python, therefore, firstly you create a list from this string: `listed_board = list(board)`. In the list, you can change element in this way: `list[index] = value` (notice index must be lower than the length of the list).
So... lets say find_all return list `[1, 3]` = > `idices = [1, 3]`. `for i in indices` == `for i in [1, 3]` => `list_board[1] = guess`, `list_board[3] = guess`.
Is that clear now? ;)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense when you break it down like that. Cheers! You are really clear with your wording. One very last thing if you don't mind :P At the very top do you know what the 'i' does before the for loop. " 'i' for i"

Comment: I assume you are asking for this part: `[i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]`. It is a list of comprehension and its  structure looks like this: [expression; for_loop; optional_condition] in your scenario expression = 'i', but it could be anything, for example, `i*i`, or `some_function(i)`. 'for_loop' = `letter in enumerate(word)`, and optional_condition = `letter == guess`.

Comment: Oh I see! So in this case it is getting the user's guess index(s) from a word and storing them in an list that is called indices when I call the function. That confuses me though, how is a single 'i' the expression in this case? What is it expressing?

Comment: it is simply `i`. This statement: `[i for i, letter in enumerate(word) if letter == guess]` can be replacet with a bit longer one: `temp = [] \n for i, letter in enumerate(word): \n if letter == guess: \n temp.append(expression)` in your case expresion = `i`, but it can be replaced as above, by any other, for example `i*i`

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks for explaining everything man! Appreciate it. Have a good one.

Comment: No problem, glad I was able to help ;)

Answer (score 1):

`enumerate(word)` returns a table of values that you can iterate over with `i, letter`. i would be the index you are iterating over and the letter is the item in the enumerated word. `i for i, letter` means you are selecting only the index if the condition (`letter == guess`) is correct.